# Highlighting duplicate selections in a group of dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a group of 8 dropdowns all with the same options in each one. These are generated programatically in the code behind. I have a small piece of javascript that checks for a duplicate selection and displays an error message which is working fine.

Ideally what I want to do as well is highlight the dropdown they selected which caused the error and the dropdowns that match what they have selected. Just an asterisk or something like that next to the dropdown. I hope that makes sense.

My code so far is:

```
<div id="error"></div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<h3>1st preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /></p>

<h3>2nd preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>3rd preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>4th preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref4" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>5th preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref5" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>6th preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref6" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>7th preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref7" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

<h3>8th preference</h3>
<p><asp:DropDownList ID="Pref8" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/></p>

</asp:Panel>
```

and the javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('select', $('#<% =Panel1.ClientID %>')[0]).change(function () {
        var instance = this;
        var isValidSelection = true;
        var $otherDropdowns = $('select', $('#<% =Panel1.ClientID %>')[0]).not($(this));
        $.each($otherDropdowns, function (i, item) {
            if (instance.value == item.value) {
                isValidSelection = false;
                $('#error').html("<span style=\"color:red\">You have selected a duplicate option</span>");

                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#error').html("");
            }
        });

        return isValidSelection;


    });
    });
```

Any help or pointers are much appreciated as my javascript/jquery is rudimentary at best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic solution that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

**Note: this will clear out all 'highlighted' dropdownlists when you make a change that does not have any duplicates.

```
$.each($otherDropdowns, function (i, item) {
        if (instance.value == item.value) {
            isValidSelection = false;
            $('#error').html("<span style=\"color:red\">You have selected a duplicate option</span>");

            $(item).addClass('highlighted') //Add the 'highlighted' class to the duplicate selection and original
            $(instance).addClass('highlighted');
            $(item).parent().append("<span>*</span>")  //Append the "*" to the parent element which is <p>
            $(instance).parent().append("<span>*</span>") //Append the "*" to the parent element which is <p>

            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#error').html("");

            //Remove the class, and remove the <span>*</span>
            $(item).removeClass('highlighted');
            $(instance).removeClass('highlighted');
            $("span", $(item).parent()).remove();
            $("span", $(instance).parent()).remove();

        }
    });
```

Then you just have to create a CSS style for `highlighted`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan. This works for me, needs a bit of fine tuning but this has given me the start I needed. So much simpler when it's in front of you, I think I was making it more complicated in my head than it actually was. Thanks.